# Can't override external javascript with css

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to override a style within a javascript form from Little Green Lights.

I can override the width within Chrome inspect, but I can't duplicate the override from my style sheet.

I thought at first I wasn't being specific enough, so I tried just putting a border around the table element but it doesn't work, which implies that the css override can't affect js code.

Am I overlooking something? Can this be done?

The code I'm using to override is

```
table[style] {
   width: 400px !important;
}
```

[image: screen shot of table element]

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML and JS?

Comment: styles values in attribut `style="..."` have priority max

Comment: `so I tried just putting a border around the table element but it doesn't work` if you had `table[style] {border: 1px solid black;}` and it wasn't applied, then you probably didn't load the stylesheet or the stylesheet was not parsed correctly.

Comment: @MisterJojo `!important` should overwrite styles in `style`  if those don't have `!important` as well.

Comment: Like Spectric said, please provide some HTML and JS. Please read up on [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).. **Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the !important rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.**

Comment: **1.**  check if the stylesheet is loaded that contains your rule. **2.** check the contents of that stylesheet in the developer console of your browser and verify that the rule is present (might be a caching issue) **3.** verify that you don't have any syntax error in the stylesheet (browsers will parse and apply all parseable rules) so a stylesheet can partially work.

Answer (score 0):

Good comments have been presented.

The style of your `<table>` element:

1. is an **inline CSS**
   (style attribute of an HTML element)
2. hence, it overrides any **internal CSS**
   (defined in the `<head>` section of an HTML page within a `<style>` element)
3. also overrides any **external CSS**
   (linked to it in the `<head>` section of each HTML page)

However, **JS should override all above mentioned CSS options**, unless they have the `!important` attribute set in their CSS.

Therefore, as mentioned in comments already, we should avoid `!important` whenever possible.

```js
document.querySelector('table').style.width = '200px'
```

Just make sure to apply above JS command **after** your template *Little Green Lights* has fully created its DOM elements (the table in this case), which does not have the `!important` attribute set originally according to your screen shot.

**Run code snippet**

```js
function changeWidth() {
  document.querySelector('table').style.width = '200px';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeWidth()">.style.width = '200px'</button>

<table style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 2px solid #eee"  width="559">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The css rule shown in the question has `!important` for the property. Due to that it would overwrite the inline style, if the stylesheet is loaded, the selector of the rule is correct, and the inline style does not have `!important`.

Comment: @t.niese good comment of yours. I have just edited my answer accordingly. **Question:** I have never seen `[style]` added to a selector in a CSS style sheet. Can you provide some comment about this?

Comment: [MDN: Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: The last code you added `table[style] { width: 400px !important; }` is exactly what the OP has and that snippet should work. `Therefore, as mentioned in comments already, we should avoid !important whenever possible.` I would consider - depending on the use-case - setting inline styles with JS even more problematic than with `!important`. No matter what problem the OP has is more likely that the stylesheet was not updated, not loaded correctly, or has syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is assuming that the table has a style attribute. If it hasn't then the width won't be set by your stylesheet entry, but it could be set by some other imported stylesheet.

When you add a style direct to the element in the browser inspect tool then the table does get a style attribute.

Here's a simple example. Table 1 has no width set and Table 2 has because it had (an albeit otherwise empty) style attribute so your selector worked.

```js
const table1 = document.querySelector('#table1');
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(table1).width);
const table2 = document.querySelector('#table2');
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(table2).width);
```

```css
table[style] {
  width: 400px !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
</table>
<table style="" id="table2">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector doesn't even work. If the syntax is right and it has `!important` attached to it, it will override the javascript:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table')
table.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
```

```css
table 
{
   background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `Your CSS selector doesn't even work. If the syntax is right …`? That sounds as if the selector would be invalid?

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions addressed the override, but the problem turned out to be unsolvable with css, as evidently, the lgl js execution takes place after the css overrides are implemented. I proved this by wrapping border code with

html that included the lgl script. The border showed, but did not include the lgl code. I did not try the js solutions, as it ended up being easier to change the lgl code and give up on trying to manipulate it externally.